# Access: how to write update from query?

Tags: ms-access

In my table `Progetti` I need to update the field `Eroso` with the query `Query2`.

The value to put on `Progetti.Eroso` has to be taken from the query `[Fatture Query]` where `[Fatture Query].[Codice Progetto] = Progetti.[Codice Progetto]`.

The problem is that the SQL that I am using in `Query2` could be wrong because I don't have the expected result: the system asks to insert `[Fatture Query].Sum`. The code in `Query2` is the following.

```
UPDATE Progetti SET Progetti.Eroso = [Fatture Query].Sum;
```

**EDIT**

This is the SQL code of `[Fatture Query]`:

```
SELECT Fatture.[Codice Progetto], Sum(Fatture.Fattura) AS [Sum]
FROM Fatture
GROUP BY Fatture.[Codice Progetto];
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query `Fatture Query` uses an aggregate function (`SUM`) any query which references this query is no longer updateable, as there is an inherent one-to-many relationship as soon as the records are aggregated.

As such, I believe you will need to use a function such as [`DSum`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32) to calculate the appropriate value for each record to be updated, e.g.:

```
UPDATE
    Progetti 
SET 
    Progetti.Eroso = DSUM("Fattura", "Fatture", "[Codice Progetto] = '" & [Codice Progetto] & "'")
```

---

If instead the query from which you are sourcing the values had **not** used an aggregate function (e.g. `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc.) then I would have suggested incorporating an `INNER JOIN` in your `UPDATE` query such that the values used to update the target field are sourced from the appropriate records in your `Fatture Query` query, e.g.:

```
UPDATE
    Progetti 
    INNER JOIN 
    [Fatture Query]
    ON
    Progetti.[Codice Progetto] = [Fatture Query].[Codice Progetto]
SET
    Progetti.Eroso = [Fatture Query].Sum
```

Comment: thanks but it says "Operation must use an updateable query"

Comment: What is the definition of your query `Fatture Query`?

Comment: sorry I didn't get. What does it mean "definition of query"?

Comment: Could you update your question with the SQL code for your query `Fatture Query`? You can view this by clicking the downwards arrow beneath the `Design` button and selecting `SQL`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your update query doesn't specify how the rows in `[Fatture Query]` match the rows in `[Progretti]` so the system doesn't know which row to look at. Try using a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
    UPDATE Progetti SET Progetti.Eroso = [Fatture Query].Sum WHERE [Fatture Query].[Codice Progetto] = Progetti.[Codice Progetto];
```

Comment: thanks but it still asks to insert `[Fatture Query].Sum`